# Why is this x86 code throwing a segfault?

Tags: macos, assembly, stack, x86-64

I am trying to add two numbers, 2 and 3, in x86 Assembly. Instead of primarily using registers I'm pushing and popping values from the stack (this is part of a project for a Forth compiler, that's why). However, my code gives me a segmentation fault. I have run it in GDB, but a backtrace does not give me any valuable information. Does anyone know exactly why this error is happening in my code? (I'm compiling it like this (on a Mac): `gcc -g -mstackrealign -masm=intel -o test test.asm`).

```
    .global _main
    .text
plus:
    add rdi, rsi
    push rdi  # push accumulated rdi value onto stack
    ret
minus:
    sub rdi, rsi
    push rdi
    ret
_main:
    push 2  # push 2 and 3 onto stack
    push 3
    pop rdi  # as preparation for the function call, load rdi and rsi with 2 and 3
    pop rsi
    call plus
    pop rax  # put result into rax
    mov rdi, rax  # then, put the result into rdi
    mov rax, 0x2000001  # exit system call
    syscall
```

Comment: `push rdi` / `ret` is equivalent to `jmp rdi`.  Return a value in RAX like a normal person. e.g. `lea rax, [rdi + rsi]`.

Comment: @Peter Cordes As I said, the reason that I'm not returning a value in RAX is that this code comes from a Forth compiler that I'm building. In Forth, the result would just be popped onto the stack, not returned. Given that, how can I make my code work - not just follow calling conventions?

Comment: Well obviously that doesn't work.  You don't *have* to map the Forth stack exactly to the x86-64 stack at every step, do you?  e.g. let the caller push the return value register.  Or can Forth functions push multiple things before returning?  In that case you could maybe pop the return address into a tmp register before pushing the return value.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'll try that and let you know how it goes.

Comment: related but not exact duplicate: [push same value onto stack and ret behaves differently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58351556) - you can do weird stuff with the stack, but you have to make sure the caller and callee agree on everything and jump to the right place.

Comment: @Peter Cordes Is there a way to make a stack that holds nothing more than variables, and doesn't correspond to the call stack in any way? Because that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: Yes, of course.  Use another register as a pointer, and use `mov` for store / load, `add` to increment / decrement, to manually implement push and pop operations.  Pick registers you won't need to use for other instructions (e.g. not RCX which you need for variable-count shifts, and not RAX or RDX which you need for division).

Comment: @PeterCordes Sorry about all of the questions! I'm just new to assembly - but what do you mean by "using another register as a pointer"? A pointer to what?

Comment: A pointer to your separately allocated array that you use as a stack data structure, i.e. as the Forth stack.

Comment: @PeterCordes Aha. I'll work from there

Comment: You could also drop `call`/`ret` and use a register for the return address. You'd have to manage that by hand of course.